# HtmlAgilityPack - Remove a agranchild from node

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I know how to remove a child of a node, but is it possible to remove a grandchild of a node using HtmlAgilityPack?

Comment: Yes. It's the same procedure. Get a reference to the node you want to be removed and invoke `Remove()` on that node. It doesn't matter if it's a grandchild or a friend's mother-in-law. Obtain a reference and `Remove()` it.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't think it is that simple!